# Reliably using doubles as std::map keys

Tags: c++, dictionary, floating-point, key, double

One of my coworkers recently brought up an interesting trick to reliably use floating point numbers as keys in something like a `std::map` in C++.

Assuming you want to case on some floating point value (like `price`), and you know that these values can only take on discrete values despite representing real numbers (say, at intervals of a certain `ticksize`), then the following code snippet reliably converts an input `price` to a `long long` price *key*:

```
double price, ticksize; // Initialized elsewhere
long long priceKey = 0;

if ((price / ticksize) < (ticksize / 2)) {
    priceKey = (long long) (price / ticksize);
} else {
    priceKey = (long long) ((price / ticksize) + (ticksize / 2));
}
```

For example, if `price = 98.05` and `ticksize = 0.05`, then we end up with the following result:

```
price / ticksize = 1960.9999999999998
ticksize / 2 = 0.025
priceKey = (long long) 1960.9999999999998 + 0.025 = 1961
```

`priceKey` could then go on to be used in something like a `std::map<long long, order_t>` to reliably retrieve orders at a particular price level.

**Is there any case where such logic would fail?** I tried working out a proof for myself of why this could work, but I don't think I have enough experience with floating point arithmetic to reason it out.

Comment: If `Price` is a NaN, your results will probably be pretty useless.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't use `double` when dealing with [Money values](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/money-pattern-the-right-way-to-represent-value-unit-pairs--net-35509) at all :-/

Comment: In financial trading systems there is often a necessary trade off between the speed of floating point arithmetic and the accuracy of fixed point. For example in the pricing of exotic options. Floating point solutions are generally "good enough" as long as you take care to minimise rounding errors between pricing stages.

Comment: `0.05` isn't accurately representable as a floating point value. so you are susceptible to rounding errors when using it as `ticksize`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I think the point of this trick is to actually mitigate the effects of rounding errors.

Comment: @JerryCoffin is there even a concept of of NaN with doubles in C++?

Comment: @Z1MM32M4N: [Yes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/signaling_NaN).

Comment: Why not just stick them in the `map` as they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you shouldn't divide by `ticksize`, you should multiply by the inverse of `ticksize`, which likely would be exactly representable as `double` considering the application you describe. This inverse would be `20.0` in your example.

Second, you can make the transformation slightly simpler and in my opinion more readable thus:

after multiplying `price` by the inverse of `ticksize`, round from double to the nearest integer, either as a `long long` (function `llround`) or as a `double` (function `nearbyint`). There is no inherent reason why you shouldn't use `double` as the key of `std::map`, as long as you use compatible hash and equality functions (the hash function should return the same hash for +0. and -0. if the equality is `==`, and probably you shouldn't use NaN as key if you are using `==` as equality).

In code:

```
priceKey = llround(price * inverseticksize);
```

Comment: I'm actually just realizing that this is precisely how it's implemented, (though without the inverse ticksize). I suppose that the call to `roundll` just always gets rid of imprecise roundoff errors, and that's why this works. Interesting, because it was originally described to me by adding the `(ticksize/2)`, instead of simply rounding.

Comment: @Z1MM32M4N The cast to `long long` truncates. Adding half something (either half one after scaling or half ticksize before scaling) is supposed to be a trick to obtain round-to-nearest behavior, but it does not round to the nearest value for some corner cases (that you would not encounter in your application): http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1