# Issues with map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I do have below struct defined

```
struct WayStruct{
    double ID;
    string Neighbours;
};
```

and below map

```
map <double,WayStruct> WayMap;
```

To add a new element to this map I use

```
WaysFind.ID=999;
WaysFind.Neighbours="test";
WayMap.insert(1234,WaysFind);
```

However I can not get this compiled. Dev-C++ end in error with

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::map<double, WayStruct>::insert(double, WayStruct&)'
```

Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong here?

When I used make_pair Dev-C++ returned with

```
   In instantiation of 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&) [with _U1 = double; _U2 = int; _T1 = const char; _T2 = WayStruct]': 
     required from here 
111 39 c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h [Error] no matching function for call to 'WayStruct::WayStruct(const int&)'
```

in file stl_pair.h

Comment: Have you tried to read documentation?

Comment: Hi Slava, yes I have. I've been scanning the net for quit a while now

Comment: There is no `insert(key, value)` method of `std::map`, so were I the compiler I'd probably complain as well.

Comment: Write `WayMap[1234]= WaysFind;`

Comment: Hi WhozCraig. Are you sure? ("http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/")

Comment: @HB1963 Where in that link does it show `(key, value)`?

Comment: @HB1963 yes I'm sure. First, I know all the overloads for `insert` for `std::map`. Secondly, if there were such an overload, *you wouldn't be here now*.

Comment: And we need to guess how you called `make_pair` right?

Comment: @Slava, apologises :WayMap.insert(make_pair(1234,WaysFind));

Comment: Your new error does not match that code.

Comment: @HB1963 you need to open new question and publish [mcve], what you show is different what you compiled

Comment: OK, Slava. Will do.

Comment: @HB1963 I doubt that

Comment: @Slava. What do you mean? New question 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668181/issues-with-map-2'

Comment: @HB1963 I mean if you create [mcve] you will realize that there is no question to ask

Answer (score 5):

`std::map::insert()` overload that you are trying to use accepts one parameter of type `std::map:value_type` which is `std::pair` not two. So common way to insert value to map is:

```
WayMap.insert( std::make_pair( 1234,WaysFind ) );
```

for C++11 you can insert the way you tried using `emplace` instead:

```
WayMap.emplace( 1234, WaysFind );
```

On side note you should beware of possible issues using `double` as a key.

Comment: I managed to get it solved. One question though. What issues could raise when using a double as key?

Comment: @HB1963 Read this article https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: @HB1963 Also this SO topic can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937085/reliably-using-doubles-as-stdmap-keys

Answer (score 1):

You have to use as follows:

```
WayMap.insert(std::pair<double,WayStruct>(1234,WaysFind));
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df5e4413eceb68be

If you have C++11  or higher compatible compiler this will also work:

```
WayMap.insert(std::make_pair(1234,WaysFind));
```

Comment: `make_pair` was available before c++11

Comment: I'd tried make_pair as well, but Dev-C++ started to complain in the header file stl_pair.h.
I will edit my question with the error message